# How to get the index of a table using one of its item as input without parsing the entire number of rows?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I have an item as input to search. I want to get the index of the table to which that entry belongs to. Kindly suggest me the way to go forward with this.

My table entry looks like this:

```
class c
{
public: 
    int x;  
    int y;  
    int z;  
};

struct 
{   
    int a;  
    int b;  
    class c *abc;
    int d;  
}lmn;
```

For example, I have element `y` belonging to class `c` and I have a set of entries. Basic requirement is to get element `d` from the available element `y` by reverse mapping and without going through the entire list of n entries. Assume element `z` stores the index of that particular entry. Please tell me how to get `d`, given `y`.

Comment: Sounds like you might want a hash-table for this. But I find the wording of your question rather confusing. All those letters...

Comment: Perhaps you should look at table lookup techniques like. hashing. You can utilize standard library's `unodered_map` functionality.